# How to call a CSJS function that uses JQuery after Dojo parser has completed?

Tags: dojo, xpages

I need to call a CSJS function which uses JQuery. The tricky part is I need to call it after the Dojo parser has completed.

The CSJS function is calling `$('#pageContainer input[type!="hidden"], #pageContainer select, #pageContainer textarea').serialize();`

I need to call `serialize()` after the Dojo parser has completed otherwise I won't have the Dojo date fields in the serialized string.

I've tried putting the call in a script block at the bottom of the page like this: `$(function() { serializeForm() });` but this is running before the Dojo parser has completed because my date picker field is missing.

I've also tried doing `dojo.ready(serializeForm())` but that gave me an error:

> TypeError: context is not a function
>   info: context is not a function

The error is coming from dojo.js line 1862

FYI: The purpose of serializing is to do a "is form dirty" check when the user tries to navigate away from the page (I had no luck with the enabledModifiedFlag I think because my app is using the dynamic content control to switch pages).

Comment: If you get a form dirty check working with the dynamic control how about posting to OpenNTF as a snippet? Sounds useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ready is expecting a call back function, remove the parenthesis, or wrap in anonymous function

```
dojo.ready(serializeForm)
```

or

```
dojo.ready(function(){serializeForm()})
```